# How to apply an existing coupon code programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, controllers, discount, coupon

I try to **apply an existing coupon code  programmatically  in a controller by coupon id**.

The only thing I found these code lines for Magento 1.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
        ->getQuote()
        ->setCouponCode($coupon)
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();
```

Does anyone know how can I do this in magento 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Checkout model session to get quote data.

```
 /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession**/

$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)
                                  ->collectTotals()
                                  ->save();
```

Remember to inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` in your constructor.

Take a look: **vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php**

Comment: so if my case i can use this code in my controller to apply an existing copon code?

Comment: my controller look like this, and form here i want to appluy the coupon:public function execute() {
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
 if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
    $test= $this->getRequest()->getPost('key'); 
 $sql ="SELECT `code` FROM `salesrule_coupon` WHERE code = '".$test."'";

 $resource = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $values = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
      return $result->setData($values);

Comment: Why use raw sql? Actually, I don't know what you're trying to do. You should inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` in your constructor.

Comment: i create a dropdown button on payment page. the values of dropdown are actually a coupons codes id's, created by the default method. so when i chose a value from dropdown i send a ajax request with the value in my controller, and with that query i make sure that the coupon code exist in db, and then i try to apply the dscount.

Comment: Seem that your question is too broad now. You should specify your question and more details. You can ask new question or update your question.

Comment: i succed to do all the thing except to apply the discount code. so everything work except the " apply discount part", so i have in my controller the id of the coupon code

Comment: now i only try to aplly the coupon in my controller

Comment: The id of the rule? not coupon code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52292/discussion-between-alin-lupoiu-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: Note that depending on where you are adding this code, totals may have already been collected and the coupon will not appear to apply with the original code. In this case you may need to run `setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)` before `collectTotals()`.